# What Javascript library encourages nice UI patterns and is appropriate for Silverlight/WPF developer?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, mvvm

I have some experience in SL/WPF. I always wanted to learn how to create nice looking JavaScript web apps that would be relatively easy to implement. Are there any JavaScript libraries that would offer nice view/viewlogic separation (MVVM?) as well as potentially a decent set of controls?
Could you recommend anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try http://knockoutjs.com/

It's a binding framework that will enable MVVM in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone should be aware of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  It has become fundamental for browser development.  The jQuery [UI plug-in](http://jqueryui.com/) is worth a look.